# Form input 100% width Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I am creating a form. I have some inputs but i'm having problems with their sizes.

Just look at the image:

[image]

I colored the col and as you can see, the third input has like a padding left and right. I cant remove it because i dont know which class I have to modify, what i tried was adding a class "removeMargin" and with CSS i did that:

```
.removeMargin{
    margin: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is the HTML for the last input

```
<div class="row mt-4">
   <div class="col-3">
     <span>Motivo de la consulta</span>
   </div>

  <div class="col-8 bg-primary">
   <input type="text" class="form-control removeMargin" >
 </div>
```

Any idea to remove the margins? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not a margin. col-8 has padding. you can remove padding this way. but try to do add another class as bellow.

css like this

```
.pad-l-r-0{        
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
 }
```

html like this

```
 <div class="col-8 bg-primary pad-l-r-0">
     <input type="text" class="form-control removeMargin" >
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maximum col in Bootstrap is 12 cols. You try with new HTML here.

```
<div class="row mt-4">
   <div class="col-3">
     <span>Motivo de la consulta</span>
   </div>

  <div class="col-9 bg-primary">
   <input type="text" class="form-control removeMargin" >
 </div>
```

Comment: I know but the column is actually occupying what i want it to occupy while the content inside the column isnt